# while statement is unable to read the correct char input

Tags: c++

hi i am new to c++ and i dont understand why my while statement doesnt work now. it was working when i tried to do it earlier.

Full code is available at: http://pastebin.com/aeH5fKwh

basically here is the while loop (i excluded all the unnecessary parts, i left the inside of the while loop intact for viewing purpose)

```
int main()
{
unsigned int seed;
char input;
bool done;


for (int round = 0; round < 5; round++)
{
    done = false;
    cout << "\nEnter seed: ";
    cin >> seed;
    cout << "\nRound 1" << endl;

    while(!done)
    {
        cout << "\nDo you wish to draw another card [y][n]: ";
        cin >> input;

        while (input != 'y' && input != 'n')
        {
            cout << "Invalid input! Please enter [y][n]!" << endl;
            cin >> input;
        }
        if (input == 'y')
        {
            dealExtra(playerHand, deck, gameInfo);
            cout << "Your cards are ";
            printHand(playerHand, gameInfo.playerCardCount);
        }
        else
            done = true;
    }
}
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

when i try entering anything that is not 'y', 'n', it will tell me that my input is invalid. But when i try to enter 'y' or 'n', it kinda just ignored it and nothing else happened.. i checked with cout statement and found that it manage to get into the if (input == 'y') statement, but it doesnt seem like it is doing anything else. Everything was fine till 20 minutes ago and i really couldnt figure out whats wrong.

Edit: i ran another test using "cout << '[' <<  input << ']' << endl;".. it seems like the program is able to get my first input, but then it just hangs there afterwards.. what i get is something like:

```
 Do you wish to draw another card [y][n]: y
 [y]
 y
 y
 y
 y
```

I compiled this on linux terminal using g++

if extra codes is needed, i'll edit and add them.. thanks!

Comment: You aren't checking for input error. Also, there might be input buffering active. Anyway, always try to present a minimal, compilable example exhibiting your error when asking for help. I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: The logical condition for the inner while loop should be thought through a little more, by hand tracing different input values and generating a logic table.  It will also be helpful to understand how C++ will short circuit logic conditions.  See this for reference: [Logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_logical)

Comment: i have edited the post as suggested.. and included the full code in a pastebin link just in case it helps.. in the mean time, i will do as you say and have a look at the debugging small program guide.. thanks

Comment: `it kinda just ignored it and nothing else happened` and `it doesnt seem like it is doing anything else` are very vague statements. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: yeah. i dont get why it is ignoring my input when it was working fine 30 minutes ago.. i have not edited the section at all. I tried using cout and cerr statement to make sure that it did get to where i want it to go..

Comment: What IDE are you using? Have you tried a clean rebuild?

Comment: Also, you do realize that the `//...` part after the `done = true;` is always executed, no matter if you enter `y` or `n`, right?

Comment: i am writing everything on gedit.. and yes i do realize that part is run regardless of whether the user input is y or n

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for input from the console, most implementations buffer characters until a newline key is pressed.

After the newline is received, the first character of the buffer is returned. **The newline still remains in the buffer as well as any extra characters.**

In your case, the second `cin >> input` statement will read the newline from the buffer.

As an experiment, try entering "frog" and single step through your program.  This should illustrate the case of residual characters in the buffer.

Try `cin.ignore(1000, '\n')` after the first `cin >> input`.  The `ignore` method will eat up any remaining characters in the buffer until the newline is found.

Answer (score 0):

Make below statements inactive

```
dealExtra(playerHand, deck, gameInfo);
printHand(playerHand, gameInfo.playerCardCount);
```

and check if it works, then try making one of the above statements active alternately to find out in which function the flow is getting lost. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel lazy to run a debugger, and plan to use cout<< statements to find a hanging call, you should flush you cout:

```
( cout << "I am here and going to hang" ).flush() ;
```

Otherwise you can't see recent output just because it's still in the output buffer. Try this and you well might see what call hangs your program.

Comment: Except where it is not used above: `cout << "Your cards are ";`

Comment: i tried that by including it before that cout statement.. doesnt seem to do any good..

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop inside `checkComputerHand`:

```
bool done = false;
while(!done)
{
    if(sum == 11 && checkAce == true)
    {
        computerHand[aceLocation].value = 11;
        done = true;
    }              
    if(sum > 11 && checkAce == true)
    {
        computerHand[aceLocation].value = 1;
        done = true;
    }
    // What if checkAce wasn't true? Infinite loop!
}
```

Also, the first two lines of newGame do not make any sense:

```
void newGame(Card playerHand[], Card computerHand[], Statistics &gameInfo)
{
    playerHand = '\0';
    computerHand = '\0';
    // ...
}
```

Array parameters are silently rewritten by the compiler as pointer parameters. So all you're doing is assigning the null pointer to those local pointers. Probably not what you intended...

Comment: thanks for the corrections.. the while loop wasnt needed after my last edit..

as for the 2nd issue, i was thinking of clearing the array so that i dont get leftover cards from the last game, but i guess thats not needed since i control the printing using playerCardCount from the Statistics struct..